# How to find every walk in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to find every single "walk" of length n through an array. A walk in this case is defined as a sequence of length n of adjacent elements (horizontal, diagonal, or vertical) in the array so that point is repeated. For example, a 2x2 matrix

[1 2]
[4 8]

would have walks of length 2: (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 8), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 8) ...
walks of length 3: (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 8), (1, 4, 2), (1, 4, 8) ... and so on

How could I implement a fast implementation of such an algorithm for small (5x5) matrices in python/numpy, possibly using some aspect of maths that I don't know currently?

Current slow implementation:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def get_walks(arr, n):
    n = n-1
    dim_y = len(arr)
    dim_x = len(arr[0])

    # Begin with every possibly starting location
    walks = [[(y, x)] for y in range(dim_y) for x in range(dim_x)]

    # Every possible direction to go in
    directions = [(0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (1, -1), (0, -1), (-1,-1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1)]

    temp_walks = []
    for i in range(n):
        # Go through every single current walk and add every 
        # possible next move to it, making sure to not repeat any points
        #
        # Do this n times
        for direction in directions:
            for walk in walks:
                y, x = walk[-1]
                y, x = y+direction[0], x+direction[1]
                if -1 < y < dim_y and -1 < x < dim_x and (y, x) not in walk:
                    temp_walks.append(walk + [(y, x)])

        # Overwrite current main walks list with the temporary one and start anew
        walks = deepcopy(temp_walks)
        temp_walks = []

    return walks
```

Comment: do your walks need to support lengths up to N or infinite?

Comment: Well the longest possible walk for any given y by x matrix would be (y*x), so finite up until n.

Comment: My bad, it was written in python 3.5, i'll update it.

Comment: **You cannot**. There are too many walks. It doesn't matter how you generate them, the sheer size of the output is too big to handle for anything other really small matrices.

Comment: To put in perspective, consider an `NxN` array. Consider the walks that go from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. Considering only right and down moves you have binomial (2N N) ways, which is already exponential. Add walks that can go up and down or left and right...

Comment: Yes, as i understand the number grows with O(n^n), but I should have mentioned I only need this for matrices 5x5 or lower.

Comment: However, I need it to be fast for these small matrices because I will be doing this many times for each matrix, with small alterations each time.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand:) The number of walks of length `l` is `n^2(huge number)`, where `huge number` grows *very* fast with `l`, and you have to sum `l` from `1` to `n`. The result is a *very rapidly* rising function in `n`.

Comment: I don't understand how you can say its impossible if i am already doing this. I'm limiting my domain to 5x5 matrices. My current implementation can find walks of length 8 in a 5x5 matrix about 25 seconds on my computer. This is rather slow but this is also the extreme end of the spectrum. I likely wont be using bigger matrices or longer walks. Furthermore, the amount of walks of length k in a nxm matrix is a subset of all the k-permutations of the elements in the matrix, and python can do this comfortably for even large numbers with itertools.permutations.

Comment: According to this small calculation, the bigger possible permutation i can find is [25 permute 5](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(25+permute+5)+*+32+%2F+10%5E9) assuming that the data inside are 32 bit, before I run out of memory. This is, again, fine because the walks are such a small subset of this number, that it should be doable for 5x5 matrices.

Comment: I wasn't saying that it's impossible, only that it's much more involved than O(n^2) as you've stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with a recursive solution. Since you want to treat only small problems, this approach can be feasible. I don't have numpy installed for python 3, so this is only guaranteed to work for python 2 as-is (but it should be fairly compatible). Also, I'm pretty sure my implementation is far from optimal.

When checking my output against yours, it occured to me that I get 200 paths for a 3x3 case, while you get 160. Looking at the paths, I think your code has some bug, and you are the one missing paths (and not me having additional ones). Here's my version:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def get_walks_rec(shape,inpath,ij,n):
    # add n more steps to mypath, with dimensions shape
    # procedure: call shorter walks for allowed neighbouring sites


    mypath = inpath[:]
    mypath.append(ij)

    # return if this is the last point
    if n==0:
        return mypath

    i0 = ij[0]
    j0 = ij[1]

    neighbs = [(i,j) for i in (i0-1,i0,i0+1) for j in (j0-1,j0,j0+1) if 0<=i<shape[0] and 0<=j<shape[1] and (i,j)!=(i0,j0)]
    subpaths = [get_walks_rec(shape,mypath,neighb,n-1) for neighb in neighbs]

    # flatten out the sublists for higher levels
    if n>1:
        flatpaths = []
        map(flatpaths.extend,subpaths)
    else:
        flatpaths = subpaths

    return flatpaths

# front-end for recursive function, called only once
def get_walks_rec_caller(mat,n):
    # collect all the paths starting from each point of the matrix

    sh = mat.shape
    imat,jmat = np.meshgrid(np.arange(sh[0]),np.arange(sh[1]))
    tmppaths = [get_walks_rec(sh,[],ij,n-1) for ij in zip(imat.ravel(),jmat.ravel())]

    # flatten the list of lists of paths to a single list of paths
    allpaths = []
    map(allpaths.extend,tmppaths)

    return allpaths

# input
mat = np.random.rand(3,3)
nmax = 3

# original:
walks_old = get_walks(mat,nmax)

# new recursive:
walks_new = get_walks_rec_caller(mat,nmax)

# timing:
number = 1000
print(timeit.timeit('get_walks(mat,nmax)','from __main__ import get_walks,mat,nmax',number=number))
print(timeit.timeit('get_walks_rec_caller(mat,nmax)','from __main__ import get_walks_rec_caller,mat,nmax',number=number))
```

For this 3x3 case with a max path length of 3, 1000 runs with `timeit` gives me 1.81 seconds with yours vs 0.53 seconds with mine (and you're missing 20% of your paths). For a 4x4 case with max length of 4, 100 runs give 2.1 seconds (yours) vs 0.67 seconds (mine).

An example path, which is present in mine but seems to be missing from yours:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! The extra paths that you mentioned are actually paths that contain the same point twice, which shouldn't be in a walk. I add a `and (i, j) not in mypath` to the end of your `neighbs = [(i,j) for...` line in order to make sure no two points repeat in a walk, and it gave the same result as my original implementation.

Comment: Also, in order to make this work for 3.5, i just had to replace
`flatpaths = []`
`map(flatpaths.extend,subpaths)`
with
`[item for subpath in subpaths for item in subpath]`

Comment: @AlexShmakov thank you for the feedback:) Sorry, it wasn't clear to me at all that you need self-avoiding walks. That also makes your problem much more tractable, now I see why you didn't understand our worries about output size.

Comment: @AlexShmakov also, if performance is essential and you have multiple cores in your machine, you should consider using something like [`multiprocessing.Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) to compute the paths for the `n^2` starting points in parallel, since these are completely independent from one another.